# Error Failed to execute aapt, when compiling project in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this error since Monday, no modifications have been made since last week. And on Monday I started giving problems.

- Glade: 2.14.1
- React-Native: 0.49.3
- compileSdkVersion 25
- targetSdkVersion 22

[image]

Comment: First, it would be easier for others to read, transfer for testing, and/or reproduce parts of your screenshot in an answer if you would post it as `code` or >quoted text (see editor controls).  Second, it would help if you would include in your question the source of the output you are presenting (what log file, output of what command executed with what type of login and account).  It would also help to list the platform you are running your code on (Windows, UNIX), along with vendor and OS release.

Comment: Oh, I understand, a mistake of mine. I was trying to do a react-native run-android, in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with React Native, one of your resource files references an nonexisting value (`dialogCornerRadius`). Locate the reference (Android Studio to the rescue) and fix it.